# Do REST API calls to WordPress trigger cron events?

Tags: wordpress

I'm planning on using WordPress as a headless CMS for a project and using the REST API to retrieve content. I have a few cron tasks that need to run fairly regularly within WordPress and I want to know if API calls are enough to trigger them, or if I'll need to add that functionality myself.

Edit: when I say cron I mean wp_cron

Comment: Can you clarify if the “*cron tasks*” you’re referencing are `wp_cron` tasks or if they’re scheduled through the server OS’ standard `cron` daemon?

Comment: wp_cron is what I mean by cron tasks

Answer (score 1):

Tasks scheduled through `WP_Cron` are evaluated to determine if the task should be run each time the `init` hook is executed [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://spinupwp.com/doc/understanding-wp-cron/). The `init` hook *should* be fired on every request for a URL that WordPress is configured to respond to, including REST API calls (although I can't find a definitive source to cite for this).

As such, calls to WordPress REST API should indeed trigger any code scheduled via `WP_Cron` and which is due to be executed per its configuration.